# d3.js Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected transform function, "null" for a translation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get these alampros Gantt Chart examples in the following github repository working so I can play with them a bit https://github.com/alampros/Gantt-Chart/

I'm totally new to D3, but on trying to run the examples I receive the above error. I've been searching for a solution online but have not been able to find one. The error is being thrown by the following function:

```
  timeAxisRenderer.draw  = function(node){
    node.transition().call(xAxis).selectAll('text')
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var xOffset = 3 + this.getBBox().width/2;
        var yOffset = 5 - this.getBBox().height;
        return 'translate('+xOffset+','+yOffset+')';
      });
  }
```

Any ideas please!?

Comment: Not really familiar with Gantt Chart example, but try adding .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)") before transition. 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870388/d3-js-throwing-error-invalid-value-for-g-attribute-transform-null-on-transi this gave me an idea)

Comment: Yes I saw that post and have tried that already. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.